# Pass a type parameter and declare a list

Tags: c#, reflection

```
public static List<customModel> getList(type customModel)
{ 
  List<customModel> tempList = new List<customModel>(10);
  return tempList;
}
```

Is it possible to return a list of type that is passed from somewhere else?
I have been doing my own project and notice that if there is any way to do this, my code will be much simpler.

Comment: Show us some pseudo code of what you'd like to happen.  Then maybe we can understand your question the way you intended.

Comment: I don't understand why there is so much hate for this question

Comment: @climbage I was wondering the same thing. The answer may be trivially obvious once you know what it is, but I think it's a difficult answer to find if you don't already know the term "generics".

Comment: @ean5533 Right, how do you google "generics" when you've never even heard of it?

Comment: @climbage - I think it was originally poorly worded, we need examples, etc.  No one is a mind reader.

Comment: @JonH That's why we have comments and edit.  It wasn't *that* bad.  I knew what he was getting at

Comment: @climbage - If you knew what he was getting at then we all should of known right?

Comment: @JonH Personally I knew what he was getting at right away, and it looks like the other answerers did too...

Comment: @ean5533 - That's fine but when asking questions most people prefer more details along with sample data, I am not pointing at this specific question, I am stating in most cases no one can read minds on here.  I was merely answering the question about "...why there is so much hate for this question".  BTW, a down vote is 99.9% not hate, it's rephrase your question or include more details.

Answer (score 10):

Do you mean by using [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) like this:

```
public static List<T> getList<T>()
{ 
  List<T> tempList = new List<T>(10);
  return tempList;
}
```

Which you can call like this:

```
var newList = getList<customModel>();
```

or prior to C# 3.0 (where `var` is not available):

```
List<customModel> newList = getList<customModel>();
```

---

The problem is, you could just as easily do this instead:

```
var newList = new List<customModel>(10);
```

Comment: I believe you're missing something

Comment: @user1713153: If `var` is an issue see my edited code. `var` is a feature introduced in C# 3.0, [see here for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

Comment: `var` is unnecessary here it's unfortunately overly used when rarely needed.

Answer (score 3):

Use a generic:

```
public static List<T> getList<T>()
{
    return new List<T>(10);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var myList = getList<int>();
```